# Quiero saber que esta mal y como podría resolverlo

Tags: javascript

```
function sumArray(array, n) {
```

// La función llamada 'sumArray' recibe como argumento un arreglo de números ordenados llamado 'array' y un número

// entero llamdo 'n' y debe devolver true si alguna combinación de dos números cualesquiera del arreglo sumados

// dan n, y devuelva false si ninguna combinación de dos números sumados da como resultado el número n.

// Ej:

// sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13)  debería devolver true ya que 2 + 11 = 13

// sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 14)  debería devolver false ya que no es posible sumar 14 con dos

números del arreglo

// Pista: Podes usar bucles/ciclos anidados

// Aclaración: No es válido sumar el mismo número dos veces

// Ej:

// sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 4)  Si bien 2 + 2 = 4 no está permitido sumar el mismo número dos
veces

// por lo tanto también debería devolver false en este caso

// Tu código acá:

```
const sumArray = (array, numero) => {
    const size = array.length;
  
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      const a = array[i];
  
      for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if (i === j) continue;
        const b = array[j];
        if (a + b === numero) return true;
      }
    }
  
    return false;
  }
};
```

Me gustaría saber que esta mal y como lo podría resolver.

Este es el error que me tira el test

```
● Funciones › sumArray › should return true with [2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 2 + 11 = 13

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false

      87 |   describe('sumArray', function() {
      88 |     it('should return true with [2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 2 + 11 = 13', function() {
    > 89 |       expect(sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13)).toBe(true);
         |                                                 ^
      90 |     });
      91 |     it('should return false.', function() {
      92 |       expect(sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 14)).toBe(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema no es tu lógica... el problema es las llaves... están mal anidadas...

La ultima llave con el punto y coma sobra.

Te sugiero utilizar mas la consola de errores.

```js
const sumArray = (array, numero) => {
    const size = array.length;
  
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      const a = array[i];
  
      for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if (i === j) continue;
        const b = array[j];
        if (a + b === numero) return true;
      }
    }
  
    return false;
  };


console.log(sumArray([1,2,3,4,5], 8));
console.log(sumArray([1,2,3,4,5], 24));
console.log(sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13));
console.log(sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 14));
```

Comment: Me retorna solo false en el test. No se porque?

Comment: Si ejecutas mi código te sale true y luego false (que es lo que debería devolver)

Comment: Acabo de incluir los 2 ejemplos que pones en tu pregunta... y retornan true y false respectivamente tambien

Comment: Si en la consola me devuelve igual que a ti pero el test me dice que la suma de (sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13)); es falso

Comment: al final de la pregunta puse el error que me tira el test

Comment: Ahi lo solucione. Muchas gracias @Pipe